# Link to multiple foreign rows from one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I really don't know how this is called so I couldn't find an answer.

For example I have the following tables:

```
Table products                        Table users
+----------+----------+----------+    +----------+----------+
| id       | name     | price    |    | username | products |
+----------+----------+----------+    +----------+----------+
| 1        | Bread    | 1.5      |    | James    | 1, 2     |
+----------+----------+----------+    +----------+----------+
| 2        | Cookies  | 2.0      |    | David    | 2, 3     |
+----------+----------+----------+    +----------+----------+
| 3        | Milk     | 1.2      |    | Paul     | 3, 1     |
+----------+----------+----------+    +----------+----------+
```

`products.id` is the foreign key for `users.products`.

I would like to get the name and price of all David's products using a MySQL query. This should return the following:

```
+----------+----------+
| name     | price    |
+----------+----------+
| Cookies  | 2.0      |
+----------+----------+
| Milk     | 1.2      |
+----------+----------+
```

The `JOIN` function would be the best to use I guess, but David can have just 1 or 100 products. Creating 100 columns to fit all products doesn't sound very efficient.

How can I realize this?

---

Currently I'm just fetching everything and filter it using PHP, this is not a problem at the moment but as the tables will grow I guess this will be very inefficient.

Comment: This is actually a very bad model...the way you are storing the products id in the users table is wrong

Comment: The design for the `'Users'` table is wrong. Instead of working around this bad design, please change the design

Comment: I guess you mean that the `users.products` column is wrong. I know it is, but I've no idea how to do it in another way (currently I'm using JSON for PHP). The problem is that the products David can have varies.

Comment: You can have multiple rows for each user i.e.one row for each product in the `Users` table. You can maintain another Boolean field to identify which ones are currently 'active' or 'applicable'. `Joins'` would be much easier in that case. Also, updating records would also be easier. In case, in future you'd want to retrieve & analyse data from historic records, that would be possible too!!!

Comment: Wow, great idea! Why didn't I think of that? I gave every product and user an id and created another table, containing `user_id` and `product_id`, which will 'link' the two tables. Is this efficient?

Comment: The method you describe is a pretty standard way of handling a many to many relationship. You have an intermediate table that contains the primary keys of each table you wish to join, and you can obtain your results by joining all three tables together.

Comment: Thanks! @SatwikNadkarny: you can post it as an answer if you like!

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen Ok.. I'll post it as an answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved by changing your data model.

```
users
+----------+----------+
| id       | username |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | Fred     |
+----------+----------+
| 2        | John     |
+----------+----------+

products                       
+----------+----------+----------+    
| id       | name     | price    |    
+----------+----------+----------+ 
| 1        | Bread    | 1.5      |   
+----------+----------+----------+ 
| 2        | Cookies  | 2.0      |  
+----------+----------+----------+   
| 3        | Milk     | 1.2      |  
+----------+----------+----------+
```

And here comes the magic: You could connect the two tables using a third table:

```
user_procuct_connections
+----------+----------+------------+    
| id       | user_id  | product_id |    
+----------+----------+------------+ 
| 1        | 1        | 2          |   ->  Fred has Cookies
+----------+----------+------------+ 
| 2        | 1        | 3          |   ->  Fred also has Milk
+----------+----------+------------+   
| 3        | 2        | 1          |   ->  John has Bread
+----------+----------+------------+
```

If you want a user to be able to own a single product only, then you can remove the id column, an make the `user_id` and `product_id` primary key together.

Then when you want to get for example all of Freds products then just

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    products
WHERE
    id IN (
    SELECT 
       product_id 
    FROM 
       user_procuct_connections 
    WHERE 
       user_id = 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM products pt
where FIND_IN_SET(pt.id,(select us.prices from users us 
WHERE us.username = "David"));
```

#### Working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f78d/2

Comment: Thanks, this was actually what I was looking for! However, I'll use Satwik Nadkarny's solution because it's easier to add and remove products that way.

Answer (score 1):

The design for the 'Users' table is wrong. Instead of working around this bad design, please change the design.

So effectively, you design could be as such:

Table Products :

```
 ID        Name      Price
 1         Bread     1.5
 2         Cookies   2.0
 3         Milk      1.2
```

Table users :

```
 Username  Products

  James       1
  James       2
  David       2
  David       3
  Paul        3
  Paul        1
```

You see, you can have multiple rows for each user i.e.one row for each product in the Users table. You can maintain another Boolean field to identify which ones are currently 'active' or 'applicable'. Joins' would be much easier in that case. Also, updating records would also be easier. In case, in future you'd want to retrieve & analyse data from historic records, that would be possible too!!!

Another thing with the current design is that times and again you'd have to work around the infamous "comma-seperated values". Let's say you have a record as such:

```
 Username     Products

  James        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

If you need to sort this data into rows, you'd have to work-around the 'Comma-seperated' values so many times. Imagine doing that for 'n' number of records!!

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score -1):

If you join the tables like:

```
SELECT name, price FROM products AS p INNER JOIN user_products AS up ON up.id = p.product_id AND up.user_id = <davids id>
```

You will get an array where first column will be the name and the second the price. You can then do what you want with it in PHP and change the array. You don't have to filter anymore.